# Visual Studio Code local run throws error - undefined variable is defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

So I went through a Microsoft online demo on how to do an httpTrigger in Visual Studio Code (language: JavaScript) to upload it to Azure Functions and it was successful.  I then started to customize the code so it can do a certain calculation.  I got the calculation to be done and I was able to print to console.

Now I'm trying to **run it locally** so I can pass TWO values to it, but testing it with one.  I noticed that in their demo, they were able to use the line:

```
const name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));
```

where in the body response up top, a default {"name": "Azure"} would present and I sent that value, which came up in their response.  Basically, they were able to assign **const name** with what value was passed in the curly braces with the key value pair {"name": "whateverIputhere"}.

So I decided to try in when running locally, below is the condensed code I am having trouble with:

```
module.exports = async function (req) {
const var1 = req.query.var1
}
```

and I've tried passing a parameter in multiple ways.  I thought I had to do it as {"var1": "1"} but it would tell me var1 is undefined during the running of the function locally.

Why am I not able to assign it as they did?

Possible clue: There is a sample.dat file that I thought I had to modify to just replace the default entries and it still brings up {"name": "Azure"} as the default entries not sure why.

I am at a loss and would love some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having an issue only because I was NOT including .query as an option to assign the variable.  All other "issues" during the description were quickly gone.  Thank you all for looking at this.